# Action Bar Menu Click issue in android 2.3

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I have 2 `Fragment`,`Fragment A` and `Fragment B`

In `Fragment A`, I have a list of items, with the `CheckBox`.
On click of the item in `Fragment A`, `Fragment B` is opened

And `Fragment B` has
an `ActionBar`, which has menus in the right corner and navigation up in the left corner. In android 2.3 when i click the action menus, corresponding event takes place.

But, when I select the `CheckBox`, the contextual action bar opens in `Fragment A`,
and now when I click any of the item, `CAB` is finished in `Fragment A` and then `Fragment B` is opened

And now in `Fragment B`, I am not able to click on the `ActionBar` menus(nothing happens). but when I click navigation up, it goes to `Fragment A`

This happens only in Android 2.3 device. I am using `appcompt support library` to make it run on lower devices.

Can anyone let me know, what's happening exactly.

Comment: Can you post some code snippets?

Comment: action bar menus work in android 2.3, but the issue is when CAB is selected in one fragment and then if i navigate to other fragment with action bar menus, there lies the issue.